# FileIsExist() not finding file

Tags: mql4

I am having an Expert Advisor (EA) look for the file "File.txt". 
The file was created by a python program. 
I can see the file in the file explorer. 
The path to the file is
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\Common\Files.
The error code for the FileIsExist() function is 5020(ERR_FILE_NOT_EXIST). 
Why does it not recognize the file? Is it looking in another directory?

```
while(!FileIsExist("File.txt", 0)){
      if(FileIsExist("File.txt", 0))
         printf("in while loop, waiting for file");
      else{
         int iErr = GetLastError();
         printf(iErr);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is in 'Common' folder, use the corresponding flag.

```
 bool exist=FileIsExist(filename,FILE_COMMON);
```

What is the idea of your code? if file does not exsist - sleep for a while (10ms) then check again

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the problem. 8 misunderstood the documentation. I though "0" meant the same as "FILE_COMMON".